Adding interaction to regression: main effect AND interaction non-significant
I've used two models on my dataset:
Model 1: clinical score ~ X + Z:  both X and Z are significant.
Model 2: clinical score ~ X + Z + X*Z: X is not significant anymore, and neither is the interaction, while Z still is.
I would have a better intuition for a case where the interaction was significant and X wasn't anymore, but what could be an explanation here? Is there a way to explore that graphically or in another way? I attached a scatterplot of clinical scores against X with different colours for high and low values of Z (it's continuous but I made it dichotomous for the plot), I really don't see how Z can be significant here if X isn't.
The R squared is virtually the same in both models, so maybe it would be better to leave the interaction out and have a straightforward interpretation. However I'm concerned that this might be p-hacking and that the loss of significance in model 2 means that the effect of X is not really there. Any thoughts on either of these points are welcome!


Likely your interaction is highly correlated with the X main effect or perhaps both main effects, inflating the variance of the parameter estimates without explaining much more of the variation in the response. A common problem with observational studies. Did the standard errors change much? What were your variance inflation factors like? It's also likely (under such correlation) that the coefficient estimates will change substantially, and that too can result in much smaller t-ratios even if the variance doesn't inflate all that much. A number of posts already on site discuss these issues.

Another possibility is that the apparent lack of significance of x comes from the scale of the z variable. In typical coding, the individual x coefficient, when x interacts with z, is the association of x with outcome when z = 0. If 0 is not a typical value for z then the individual coefficient for x might not have any practical importance. Consider editing this question to show the actual summaries of the models with and without the interaction and to say more about what x and z represent. I suspect that your model still contains a lot of useful information.

Thanks so much Glen_b and EdM, you were both right! X and Z were scaled differently such that 0 < X < 1 while Z was in the ten thousands, and therefore the interaction was highly correlated with it. After centering the issue was resolved. Something else I hadn't considered is that it's not just that 0 is an unnatural value for X or Z to have (these are biological variables so 0 is almost impossible), but more importantly that one can't really change if the other is 0 because they are highly correlated.

You seem to have solved your problem, so you can self-answer (in the answer box)
